# what is the meaning of negative dimension in keras theano

Tags: deep-learning, keras, theano

I've tried define a simple architecture to use on MNIST dataset , I start defined my architecture like this :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape = (1,28,28)));
```

in this step I checked my network out put :

```
model.output_shape
```

it gives me this :

```
(None, -1, 26, 32)
```

could someone explain to me what is the meaning of negative dimension (-1) ?

Comment: It means unknown dimension. It is unknown in the current context, but it will be inferred or learnt in the running such as after providing batch size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a -1 can actually be an unknown size when working directly with tensors, Keras layers don't work like that. The unknown batch size in Keras is the `None` dimension.

For convolutions, Keras uses `channels_last` as data format, so you should shape your data as `(28,28,1)`, which is (imageSide1, imageSide2, channels)

By shaping your data as (1,28,28), the convolution will think the first image side is 1 pixel. And removing the 2 pixels by the operation, it will result in -1. So, shape it as (28,28,1) to get an output of (None,26,26,32).

Alternatively, you can set the `data_format` parameter in the convolutional layer to `channels_first`, or even change the `keras.json` file to have `channels_first` as default.

Comment: how did you learn this stuff :D ? could you introduce some useful resource for me to carry on ?

Comment: Had to call "Daniel.fit(trainingWithKeras,expectedResults,epochs=a lot)". I find it hard to come up with good, short and useful tutorials. All of them talking too much and explaining more theory than practical usage. Some resources: [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/) is very very useful if you're not starting from zero. For understanding dimensions, [I wrote this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012309/keras-layers-toturial-and-samples/44014134#44014134).