# Activation function error in a 1D CNN in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm creating a model to classify if the input waverform contains rising edge of SDA of I2C line.

My input has 20000 datapoints and 100 training data.

I've initially found an answer regarding the input in here [Keras 1D CNN: How to specify dimension correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088859/keras-1d-cnn-how-to-specify-dimension-correctly)

However, I'm getting an error in the activation function:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 1)
```

My model is:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_filter,
             kernel_size=input_filter_length,
             strides=1,
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(20000,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=None))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate)

model.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, train_label,
      nb_epoch=10,
      batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

score = np.asarray(model.evaluate(test_new_data, test_label, batch_size=batch_size))*100.0
```

I can't determine the problem in here. On why the activation function expects a 3D tensor.

Comment: What task do you want to solve using this network? Classification? Regression? Could you provide more details on model compilation, fitting and model target?

Comment: This is binary classification problem. I've added more codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that starting from `keras 2.0`, a `Dense` layer applied to a sequence will apply the layer to each time step - so given a sequence it will produce a sequence. So your `Dense` is actually producing a sequence of 1-element vectors and this causes your problem (as your target is not a sequence).

There are several ways on how to reduce a sequence to a vector and then apply a `Dense` to it:

1. `GlobalPooling`:

   You may use `GlobalPooling` layers like `GlobalAveragePooling1D` or `GlobalMaxPooling1D`, eg.:

   ```
   model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_filter,
            kernel_size=input_filter_length,
            strides=1,
            activation='relu',
            input_shape=(20000,1)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=None))

   model.add(Dense(1))
   model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
   ```
2. `Flattening`:

   You might colapse the whole sequence to a single vector using `Flatten` layer:

   ```
   model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_filter,
            kernel_size=input_filter_length,
            strides=1,
            activation='relu',
            input_shape=(20000,1)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=None))
   model.add(Flatten())

   model.add(Dense(1))
   model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
   ```
3. `RNN` Postprocessing:

   You could also add a recurrent layer on a top of your sequence and make it to return only the last output:

   ```
   model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_filter,
            kernel_size=input_filter_length,
            strides=1,
            activation='relu',
            input_shape=(20000,1)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=None))
   model.add(SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=False))

   model.add(Dense(1))
   model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
   ```

Comment: Yes I intend to add 4 more convolution layer, a flattening layer before the dense. However, the relu part has an error. Even with just one CNN layer.

Comment: It's not `relu` part. It's `sigmoid`. `activation_1` comes from first stand-alone activation which is the last layer. Moreover - as I work with `Keras` a lot - I know that this comes from a target shape mismatch. Try one of my solutions and check that this will work.

Comment: Yes, the flatten does work! I plan to use Global Pooling but Flattening is the simplest so I've tried it first.

Answer (score 0):

`Conv1D` has its output with 3 dimensions (and it will keep like that until the Dense layer).

Conv output: (BatchSize, Length, Filters)

For the Dense layer to output only one result, you need to add a `Flatten()` or `Reshape((shape))` layer, to make it (BatchSize, Lenght) only.

If you call `model.summary()`, you will see exactly what shape each layer is outputting. You have to adjust the output to be exactly the same shape as the array you pass as the correct results. The `None` that appears in those shapes is the batch size and may be ignored.

---

About your model: I think you need more convolution layers, reducing the number of filters gradually, because condensing so much data in a single Dense layer does not usually bring good results.

**About dimensions:** [keras layers toturial and samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012309/keras-layers-toturial-and-samples)

Comment: Actually, the error is in the first activation function. As I understand, the output after the filter should have been (100,1) and the number of filters. That's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: Call model.summary() and confirm the dimensions.

Comment: This error is typical, the output dimension of "your model" is not the same dimension as the "targets array" (train_label) you pass to fit.