# Dimensions issues with deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, classification, dimension

I seem to have some problems understandind how the [model](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CNN_ASLPTrans2-14.pdf) described in this paper has been designed

This is what is written about the model dimension..

> ...In these experiments we used one convolution ply, one poolingply
>   and two fully connected hidden layers on the top. The fullyconnected
>   layers had 1000 units in each. The convolution andpooling parameters
>   were: pooling size of 6, shift size of 2,filtersize of 8, 150 feature
>   maps for FWS..

So according to ^ does the model consist of

Input

Convolution

Pooling

Input being the 150 feature maps (each with shape (8,3)

Covolution being 1d as kernel size is 8

and pooling is with size 6 and stride 2.

What was expected of output would be a shape of (1,"number of filters), but what i get is (14,"number of filters)

Which I understand why i get, but I don't understand how the paper suggest this can give an output shape of (1,"number of filters")

when using 100 filters I get these outputs from each layer

convolution1d give me (33,100)

pooling (14,100)..

**Why i expect the output to be 1 instead of 14**

The model is supposed to recognise phones, it takes in a 50 frames (150 including deltas) as input, these being a context frame, meaning that these are used as support to detect one single frame... That usually why context windows are used.

Comment: It isn't clear what this question is asking I followed you in till the very end what results did you get and what was that not expected

Comment: Hope it make more sense now..

Answer (score -1):

As I understand from your question, the shape `(14,'number of filters)` comes out after the pooling layer. That is expected.

What you have to do is to flatten the results in to a single vector before feeding them to the two layer fully connected networks.

Marcin Morzejko's answer to my question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112236/activation-function-error-in-a-1d-cnn-in-keras) would help.

Comment: I don't think "reshaping" the result is a possibility here..  
The model proposed isn't suggesting one to alter it, and that may affect the perfomance of the model...

Comment: I don't think reshaping the output is a proper solution.. I would like to have to math correct to avoid messing with things.